# How to escape single quotes in a bash script run from Jenkins?

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I am trying to escape single quotes in parameters that are passed to a Bash script which is run on Jenkins. I am wondering if there is a way for me to escape these single quotes through Jenkins, or do I need to change the code to escape them.

I have already tried passing parameters like you're or we've, by doing this: you\'re as well as you\'\re but the Jenkins job automatically fails, but youre and weve works just fine. I can try running this manually in the command line and escaping the apostrophes there, however, I would like this process to be simplified.

"sed -ie 's/lms.facebook.keywords=.*\$/lms.facebook.keywords=${KEYWORDS}/g'

The parameters being passed to Jenkins become populated in: ${KEYWORDS}.

When trying to pass a parameter that has an apostrophe, the job automatically fails and returns this:

```
bash: -c: line 8: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing the Jenkin's parameter you're

use double quotes for that variable

like

```
"$apostrophes"
```

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation in shell script works with double quotes.

```
"sed -ie 's/lms.facebook.keywords=.*\$/lms.facebook.keywords="${KEYWORDS}"/g'"
```